Difference in the Domain of Intermediate Functions and the Solution Function
Difference in the Domain of Intermediate Functions and the Solution Function
I am asked to solve the differential equation
$$x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = x^2 \sin{x}.$$
The process I followed to try to solve it was:
Dividing by (x):
$$\frac{dy}{dx} - y \frac{1}{x} = x \sin{x}.$$
Therefore, (x \neq 0). Then I found the integrating factor (\mu = \frac{1}{|x|}) and multiplied the equation by it:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{1}{|x|} - y \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{|x|} = x \sin{x} \frac{1}{|x|}.$$
To simplify, I assumed (x > 0), so the previous equation simplifies to:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{1}{x} - y \frac{1}{x^2} = \sin{x}.$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{x} y \right) = \sin{x}.$$
$$\int \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{x} y \right) \, dx = \int \sin{x} \, dx.$$
$$\frac{1}{x} y = -\cos{x} + k.$$
Finally,
$$y = -x \cos{x} + kx.$$
To verify my exercises, I compare my results with Wolfram Alpha. According to my analysis, my family of solutions can only accept (x > 0) due to the intermediate algebraic procedures. However, Wolfram accepts all real values for x, which also makes more sense to me. So, what is my conceptual error?. Is it a fundamental problem in my understanding?

You don't even need to multiply by $\frac{1}{|x|}$, as you did in an intermediate step. Just divide by $x$, and you should get the same result, without any restriction on the domain of $x$ (except $x = 0$).

Also note that writing $x \sin x \frac{1}{|x|}$ is potentially ambiguous. Instead, you should use $\frac{x}{|x|} \sin x$.

@K.Jiang its true!, thanks for the advice. I just noticed I did a lot of Latex errors too.

Somewhat more generally, consider a differential equation $F(x, y, y', \ldots, y^{(n)})$ where $F$ is an analytic function on $\mathbb C^{n+2}$, and a function $u(x)$ that is analytic
on a connected domain $D \subseteq C$.  If $y = u(x)$ is a solution of the differential equation on some interval of positive length, then it is a solution on the whole domain $D$.  So you can basically assume $x$ is in any interval that you wish, and if this leads you to a solution that works on that interval, it should also work on the whole domain where your solution can be defined.

You did no error, at $x=0$ the differential equation has a singularity, it loses the derivative. Thus as ODE the domain is split along the y-axis. Solutions in the left and right half-plane are at first independent.
Now in this special case all solutions have a limit at the origin, so you can continue through the origin as a continuous function with different constants $k$ at each side. Moreover, demanding a continuously differentiable solution is possible, and is uniquely realized by having the same constant $k$ on each side.
That the $y$-axis does not belong to the domain of the ODE is quickly demonstrated by the fact that no point on it can serve as initial condition, except the origin where the solution is not unique. (Remember that the domain is an open set, so the origin alone can not added the the open half-planes.)
